# How can I set the Scout Ships to automatically attack nearby?

Tags: age-of-empires

In Age of Empires 1 is there any way to configure the [Scout Ships](http://ageofempires.wikia.com/wiki/Scout_Ship) so that they automatically attack any  [Fishing Boats](http://ageofempires.wikia.com/wiki/Fishing_Boat_(Age_of_Empires)) that are nearby? By default they seem to stand idle.

Fishing Boats:

[image]

Scout Ships:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're set to neutral with that person. You need to be set to enemy.

Neutral causes military units and towers to automatically attack enemy military units. They don't automatically attack civilian units such as villagers or fishing boats (but can be ordered to).

Enemy causes your military to attack everything.

[image]

Comment: Aww yiss, that nostalgia screenshot.